# Want to display customer frequency date and plot graph in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, pivot

Below is my data I want to get this type of data

mydata:

```
Cohort  JoinDate    RenewDate   PurchaseValue
c10231  01-01-2014  01-01-2014  30007
c10232  02-01-2014  02-01-2014  364
c10233  04-01-2014  04-01-2014  14952
c10233  04-01-2014  04-01-2014  18869
c10234  05-01-2014  05-01-2014  30558
c10235  01-02-2014  01-02-2014  18514
c10237  01-02-2014  01-02-2014  7245
c10231  01-01-2014  01-02-2014  24064
c10232  02-01-2014  03-02-2014  25846
c10236  05-02-2014  05-02-2014  30626
c10234  05-01-2014  05-02-2014  5560
c10233  04-01-2014  05-02-2014  17121
c10237  01-02-2014  01-03-2014  29633
c10231  01-01-2014  01-03-2014  9352
c10238  02-03-2014  02-03-2014  27463
c10232  02-01-2014  02-03-2014  12510
```

output:

```
Count of Cohort Column Labels                           
            Jan                             Feb  Mar            Grand Total
Row Labels  01-Jan  02-Jan  04-Jan  05-Jan       01-Mar 02-Mar  
       Jan       1       1       2       1    4       1      1           11
       Feb                                    3       1                   4
       Mar                                                   1            1
Grand Total      1       1       2       1    7       2      2           16
```

I want R script to display data as show in below mentioned data-- the data is which is frequency of cohort. I did in Excel by pivot- tables ,but I want the same output as in R.

column'data -->Joindate rows date --->RenewDate Values-->freqency(Cohort) 
[image]

Comment: i want r script to get output as mentioned above .

Comment: If you show us what you have tried so far, we can help you figure out how to do what you don't know how to do.